# How to update an integer value in Mongodb while preserving type

Tags: mongodb

I want to include some values by a percent.

i.e. give a document with `"A": 1700` I want to update it to A: (1700* 1.15)

```
{$mul: {"A": 1.15}}
```

but doing so with `$mul` I get weird results for some values, like 1954.99999998 and it changes the type to a double.

Does a valid syntax exist for an operation like this?

```
{
    $set: {
        "A" : {$trunc: ("A" * 1.15)}
    }
}
```

this is not value either

```
{
     $set: {
        "A" :  NumberInt("A" * 1.15)
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into documentation of [$mul](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/#up._S_mul) you will see that this operator can change the element data type and you can't controll it. Unfortunately you can't use any arithmetic operations directly in `$set` operator. In this case (when you want to apply the additional operations to multiplied value) you need read the element value, apply your custom operations and then save it into DB.

Comment: so basically this calculation cannot be done with a mongodb query? I must write a client-side script? Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately yes.